# Center align italic number in siunitx S-column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

Here is a table with the `siunitx` S column type.  I would like the italic value (the command with `swapshift`) to be still centered on the decimal point.  The superscript can be variable, but will almost always be just "a" or "b", maybe "c", never more than 1 letter in length.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product={}\cdot{},sticky-per=true,multi-part-units=single,separate-uncertainty=true,list-units=single,range-units=single,detect-all,detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\thirteenc}{\textsuperscript{13}C}
\newcommand{\oneh}{\textsuperscript{1}H}
\robustify\bfseries
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}
\setcounter{BPCno}{200}

\newcommand{\mcol}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\mrow}[3]{\multirow{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\onemultcol}[2]{\mcol{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\rule{1.2em}{0em}}r@{ }l}
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{$#1$}
\newcommand{\range}[1]{\mcol{1}{c}{\bfseries #1}}
\newcommand{\swapshift}[2]{\mcol{1}{c}{\textit{#1}\textsuperscript{#2}}}
\newenvironment{onehTable}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{gS[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]} \toprule%
\mcol{2}{c}{\mrow{2}{*}{Position}} & \mcol{2}{c}{Computed} & \mcol{2}{c}{Experimental} \\%
& & \mcol{1}{c}{\textbf{#1}} & \mcol{1}{c}{\textbf{#2}} & \mcol{1}{c}{\textbf{#1}} & \mcol{1}{c}{\textbf{#2}} \\%
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](r){1-2} \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){3-4} \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){5-6}}%
{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\CNlabelsubnoref{carvomenthone}{cis}
\CNlabelsubnoref{carvomenthone}{trans}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Calculated and Experimental \oneh{} Shifts (in ppm) for carvomenthones \CNref{carvomenthone}}\label{tab:SI:carvomenthone1H}
    \begin{onehTable}{\CNrefsub{carvomenthone}{cis}}{\CNrefsub{carvomenthone}{trans}}
    2 & & 2.47 & 2.48 & 2.45 & 2.33 \\
    3 & \greek{\alpha} & 1.87 & 1.29 & \swapshift{1.87}{a} & 1.30 \\
    3 & \greek{\beta} & 1.70 & 2.12 & \range{1.60--1.75} & 2.10 \\
    10 & Me & 1.06 & 0.92 & 1.10 & \swapshift{1.01}{b} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{onehTable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With this data you could use `\newcommand{\swapshift}[2]{\mcol{1}{c}{\kern0.1em\textit{#1}\rlap{\textsuperscript{#2}}}}`, but that won't work with all range of numerical data.  Not sure if there is a proper way to eliminate the `\kern0.1em` fudge factor, but that was required since this text is in italics.

Comment: @PeterGrill Sorry, I keep getting an `Undefined control sequence,<argument> \textsuperscript{a}...` error now with that updated `swapshift` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying your example a bit, I think you want something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox,multirow,siunitx}
\robustify\itshape
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{table-format = 1.2, detect-all}
  \begin{tabular}
    {
      >{\rule{1.2em}{0em}}
      r@{ }
      l
      S
      S
      S[table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{a}]
      S[table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{b}]
    }
    \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Position}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Computed} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Experimental} \\
       & &
         {\textbf{201a}} & {\textbf{201b}} & {\textbf{201a}} & {\textbf{201b}} \\
       \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](r){1-2}
         \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){3-4}
         \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){5-6}
       2 &          & 2.47 & 2.48 &         2.45                       & 2.33 \\
       3 & $\alpha$ & 1.87 & 1.29 & \itshape 1.87{\textsuperscript{a}} & 1.30 \\
       3 & $\beta$  & 1.70 & 2.12 & {\bfseries 1.60--1.75}             & 2.10 \\
      10 & Me       & 1.06 & 0.92 &         1.10                      &
        \itshape 1.01{\textsuperscript{b}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The key here is to use `\itshape` to alter the formatting while retaining `siunitx` `S` column alignment, plus setting up so space for the superscript using `table-space-text-post`.

I've also cut down on the use of `\multicolumn`, as `{...}` will escape thing from `siunitx` more clearly. `siunitx` treats anything inside a wrapping set of braces as 'text', so for example

```
& {\bfseries 1.60--1.75} &
```

typesets the material without parsing the number: the alignment of 'text' is governed by the `table-text-alignment` key. (You could alternatively use `\multicolumn` and `\tablenum`, but that seems overly complex here.)

The `table-space-text-post` setting reserves 'some space' for additional  material after the number. It needs to be wide enough when typeset to hold the largest item you will have after the text in a column. Usually, this is simply a case of picking something representative, although if the letter width varies a lot in your font then that may be an issue. I've used superscript `a` and `b` as they are the only things in those columns: I guess if you have an `m` or `w` to fit in you'll need to use them as they are wider!

Comment: Ah wonderful!  Can you explain your comment about the `multicolumn` and the `{...}` what is the `{...}`?  Also, is there a way to use use the `table-space-text-post` for more than one possibility?  I have one particularly nasty NMR spectra that requires superscripts up to the letter `g` in one column.

Comment: Thank you so much for the added explanation, definitely help me understand better!  I've implemented it into my thesis, and it works great.