# Unaligned italic numbers in table when using siunitx

Tags: tables, fonts, siunitx, italic

I am trying to construct some tables using the package `siunitx`. As you can see in the example below, the number in column `D` are nicely aligned in the first three rows (after the header). However, the last number (46.57%) in the last row is not aligned anymore. I somehow guess that is related to the usage of `\itshape` (I followed the advice giving [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70189/center-align-italic-number-in-siunitx-s-column)).

**Do you have any idea how to correctly align the figures in the last row using an italic font shape?**

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{
        group-digits=true,       
        group-minimum-digits=4,
    add-integer-zero=false,
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{center}
  \caption{Some Table}
  \begin{tabular}{c
          c
          S[table-format = 2.0]
          S[table-format = 2.2]}
    \toprule
    A & B & {C} & {D} \\ \midrule
    1 & 24 & 12 & 50.00\% \\ 
    2 & 22 & 4 & 18.18\% \\ 
    3 & 85 & 45 & 52.94\% \\ \midrule
    \emph{Total} & \emph{131} & {\itshape 61} &  {\itshape 46.57\%}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT:**

**New MWE based on the comments and answers:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\itshape

\usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{
        group-digits=true,       
        group-minimum-digits=4,
    add-integer-zero=false,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \sisetup{detect-all = true, table-space-text-post = \%}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}
          c
          c
          S[table-format = 2.0]
          S[table-format = 2.2]
          @{}}
    \toprule
    A & B & {C} & {D}  \\ \midrule
    1 & 24 & 12 & 50.00\% \\ 
    2 & 22 & 4 & 18.18\% \\ 
    3 & 85 & 45 & 52.94\% \\ \midrule
    \emph{Total} & \itshape 131 & \itshape 61 &  \itshape 46.57\% \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I guess I am missing something important here. However, this table (in particular column C and D) does not look right. The numbers in column C are shifted to the left. In addition, the percentage sign is still to close to the right column border. Any suggestions? (Sorry for the detailed and stupid-sounding questions. However, this table starts to steal my sanity.)

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells (`\itshape` _vs_ `\bfseries` is the only real difference)

Comment: Thanks. I tried using `\usepackage{etoolbox} \robustify\itshape`. However, this did not change anything. Maybe I did not really understand the solution given in the link you just posted.

Comment: You also need to allow `siunitx` to detect shape (the standard settings force upright): I'd probably `detect-all` here.

Comment: Alright. However, I added `detect-all` and later also `detect-weight=true` and `detect-inline-weight=math` to my `\sisetup`. Still no changes...

Comment: Don't make the option `table-space-text-post = \%` global, i.e., apply to columns C and D. Make it apply only column D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach is much the same as in [siunitx: Bold single numeric cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells): make `\itshape` robust, allow `siunitx` to find it at the start of a cell, allow `siunitx` to pick an appropriate font.

### Version 3

For v3 (current release), the code you'd want is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\itshape

\usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{
        group-digits=all,       
        group-minimum-digits=4
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \sisetup{mode = text, reset-text-shape = false}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}
          c
          c
          S[table-format = 2.0]
          S[table-format = 2.2]
          @{}}
    \toprule
    A & B & {C} & {D/\%} \\ \midrule
    1 & 24 & 12 & 50.00 \\ 
    2 & 22 & 4 & 18.18 \\ 
    3 & 85 & 45 & 52.94 \\ \midrule
    \emph{Total} & \itshape 131 & \itshape 61 &  \itshape 46.57\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want units in each row (which is generally not recommended though it is commonly done), then you need to allow for the space in the appropriate column(s):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\itshape

\usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{
        group-digits=true,       
        group-minimum-digits=4,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \sisetup{mode = text, reset-text-shape = false}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}
          c
          c
          S[table-format = 2.0]
          S[table-format = 2.2\,\%]
          @{}}
    \toprule
    A & B & {C} & {D} \\ \midrule
    1 & 24 & 12 & 50.00\,\% \\ 
    2 & 22 & 4 & 18.18\,\% \\ 
    3 & 85 & 45 & 52.94\,\% \\ \midrule
    \emph{Total} & \itshape 131 & \itshape 61 &  \itshape 46.57\,\%\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Version 2

With the older version 2 (which you can test if you like with `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]}`, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\itshape

\usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{
        group-digits=true,       
        group-minimum-digits=4,
    add-integer-zero=false,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \sisetup{detect-all = true}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}
          c
          c
          S[table-format = 2.0]
          S[table-format = 2.2]
          @{}}
    \toprule
    A & B & {C} & {D/\%} \\ \midrule
    1 & 24 & 12 & 50.00 \\ 
    2 & 22 & 4 & 18.18 \\ 
    3 & 85 & 45 & 52.94 \\ \midrule
    \emph{Total} & \itshape 131 & \itshape 61 &  \itshape 46.57\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You can use a similar approach for the units-on-each-line, but there you'll need `S[table-format = 2.2, table-space-text-post = \,\%]` as v2 can't pick up the post-numerical part from `table-format`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having trouble with this: when I tried [Joseph's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331241/262365) I just didn't get any italics shown, the font was all upright. However, this did not happen with the `\bfseries` command, only the `\itshape` command.

What solved it for me was changing `\usepackage{siunitx}` with `\usepackage{siunitx-v2}`. According to the log, this changes from v3.0.37 to v2.8e. It's kind of a pain because, for example, this old version of siunitx apparently cannot deal with scientific notation values (i.e. `2.3e4`) and I had to change those.

There is [a closed issue in siunitx's tracker](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/306) about a similar problem, but it supposed to be fixed. I'll try to report this.